# parse.com get list of data i/o failure

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to get an table all details I tried like this -

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("ProfileData");
    query2.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> profileList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (profileList.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < profileList.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject p = profileList.get(i);

                        Log.d("ParseQuery", "objectId: " + p.getString("objectId"));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

But I am getting an

> Error: i/o failure

**Table looks like this -**

[image]
Am I doing something wrong?

I am adding my log this log is showing before getting this error. Might be it's having some clue.
**Full Log added:-**

```
01-03 12:51:02.441 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
01-03 12:51:02.491 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
01-03 12:51:02.501 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
01-03 12:51:02.501 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab I/Adreno200-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.041_msm8660_surf_JB_REL_RB1.2_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
                                                                         Build Date: 11/05/12 Mon
                                                                         Local Branch: mybranch425650
                                                                         Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_rb1.2
                                                                         Local Patches: NONE
                                                                         Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.041 +  NOTHING
01-03 12:51:02.741 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-03 12:51:02.972 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
01-03 12:51:02.972 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 523: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-03 12:51:02.972 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-03 12:51:02.972 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
01-03 12:51:02.972 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 525: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-03 12:51:02.972 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-03 12:51:02.982 32042-32046/com.android.googlemapwithtab D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4558K, 28% free 14380K/19843K, paused 38ms+49ms, total 172ms
01-03 12:51:03.302 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-03 12:51:06.065 32042-32046/com.android.googlemapwithtab D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4499K, 25% free 16899K/22407K, paused 41ms+16ms, total 164ms
01-03 12:51:30.929 32042-32042/com.android.googlemapwithtab D/score: Error: i/o failure
```

Comment: your code looks ok for me, please paste the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

1)Before proceeding just check from parse.com that you tablename key name are correct.

2)Surround the code with try{}catch(Throwable t){} to avoid any kind of exception stopping your app.

3) Just try debugging to find exact issue and just provide some more details.So that you may get some more better solution.

4) Prefer android studio to have better debugging.

Comment: Table name is same.  My error got printed in this line - Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage()); Debugging is not working in that part of the code. I am using android studio.

Answer (score 0):

[debug button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8OQY.png)

> This press this button

[Device Debug access button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcJDA.png)

> Then press if your not getting the device access to debug

Comment: I know how to debug you try to put a debugger inside the done overridden method. You can see what I am trying to mean.

Comment: Check you have added this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: **Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());** Let me know what this **e** is from and **details** while **debugging** it.